# How to start a background thread in Android

Tags: android

This might be a stupid question, but I'll ask it anyway.

How do you start a background thread off the UI thread without using AsyncTask or Handler or Service or any other Android-provided structure? I want to create a `new Thread` to do some Bitmap processing, and given the bugs that were reported against AsyncTask, I'd like to avoid those classes. I know they are the Google-recommended way to background a task, but let's pretend I *can't* use them...just for fun. :)

If it's not possible, I'd like to know why. If it is, how do I do this?

Comment: I imagine someone with this amount of reputation would search it here for similar questions first. There are literally tens of them.

Comment: @Zabri Would you link me to one that specifically excludes AsyncTask/Handler/Service classes? I know that I *can*  `new Thread`, but I want to *make certain* that I can call that from anywhere (even the main UI thread) and it still functions as intended (a non-UI-blocking task).

Comment: Where else would you want to call it from than from the main thread? And that's kind of the purpose - to have a background task that doesn't block the main UI thread. Look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads Especially on the second example in _Worker threads_. You could process your `Bitmap` in a similar way there.

Comment: Ah, see, that's the kind of information I was looking for in the first place! My Google searches have been linking me to SO posts that only suggest AsyncTask/Handler/Service...no explanation or anything. Thanks very much

Comment: Thanks for putting it as an answer! I usually have to ask :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start a `new Thread` from the *main UI thread* for `Bitmap` processing no problem. It will do what you need it to do and won't block the *main UI thread* in any way. However you can't directly manipulate your *UI thread* from the newly created thread.

Look for more information here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads

Answer (score 0):

You could try with `Thread`

```
Thread initBkgdThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
     public void run(){


         //Things that you wanted to do in background here.

      }
});
initBkgdThread.start();
```

Comment: If you create a new thread on the main UI thread, will that be a problem?

Comment: It should be fine, you can run this on UI thread. I tried using this within runOnUiThread before

Comment: @DarrenGreen running lager functions on UI thread may cause ANR exception

Answer (score 0):

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{   
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
       // Your code here                        
    }
}).start();
```